# To what does the regexpression ':[^:]+:[^:]+:[^:]+*' match

Tags: regex, oracle

```
substr( regexp_substr(data,':[^:]+:[^:]+:[^:]+*', 1, 1),
        length(regexp_substr(data,':[^:]+:[^:]+:*', 1, 1)) + 6
)
```

I dont have access to what  `data` in `reg_substr` represent. When I'm trying to check with some arbitary(dummy) data, I'm getting `null` as result. Please explain what the reg expression `':[^:]+:[^:]+:[^:]+*'` represent with an example. Thank you.

What is the significance of `:` in reg expression.

Comment: All I see are space invaders!

Comment: @Liath that's pacman fool

Comment: `+*` shouldn't be a legal character, although `*+` is legal in some languages. I'm pretty sure that's a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression:

```
:[^:]+:[^:]+:[^:]+*
```

Matches:

- A colon `:` character
- One-or-more characters which are not a colon `:`
- A colon `:` character
- One-or-more characters which are not a colon `:`
- A colon `:` character
- Any one-or-more characters which are not a colon `:` then the `*` on the end means that this previous match `[^:]+` is matched zero-or-more times.

`[^:]+*` is valid but does not make much semantic sense - instead it can be rewritten as the equivalent expression `[^:]*` (Zero-or-more characters which are not a colon `:`).

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/22280)

**Query 1**:

```
WITH strings AS (
            SELECT ':abcd:efg:hijk' AS string FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL SELECT 'test :1234:5:' FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL SELECT '::x:y::' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT string,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( string, ':[^:]+:[^:]+:[^:]+*' ),
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( string, ':[^:]+:[^:]+:[^:]+' ),
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( string, ':[^:]+:[^:]+:[^:]*' )
FROM   strings
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/22280/0)**:

```
|         STRING | REGEXP_SUBSTR(STRING,':[^:]+:[^:]+:[^:]+*') | REGEXP_SUBSTR(STRING,':[^:]+:[^:]+:[^:]+') | REGEXP_SUBSTR(STRING,':[^:]+:[^:]+:[^:]*') |
|----------------|---------------------------------------------|--------------------------------------------|--------------------------------------------|
| :abcd:efg:hijk |                              :abcd:efg:hijk |                             :abcd:efg:hijk |                             :abcd:efg:hijk |
|  test :1234:5: |                                    :1234:5: |                                     (null) |                                   :1234:5: |
|        ::x:y:: |                                       :x:y: |                                     (null) |                                      :x:y: |
```

Comment: @MTO so you mean to say that the first and last expressions results in the same pattern..!?

Comment: Yes `[^:]+*` will look for `[^:]+` zero-or-more times so will look for an empty string or `[^:]+` or `[^:]+[^:]+` (which is the same as `[^:]+`) or `[^:]+[^:]+[^:]+` (which is the same as `[^:]+`) and so on... which is, functionally, exactly the same as `[^:]*`.

Answer (score 1):

Colon is not special. This would match a single colon, followed by anything not a colon (multiple characters), followed by a colon, followed by ...

I'm not sure what the asterisk on the end is there for -- I don't think it has any effect (and it might be an error).

As far as I can tell, this command will return 6 characters formatted :a:b:c (which means ':[^:]:[^:]:[^:]' would be an equivalent regex).

Comment: Asterisk is zero or more of the preceding but '+*' doesn't make sense to me

Comment: I know what *AN* asterisk is for. I don't know what *THE* asterisk is for. ;)

Comment: I'm still saying space invaders ;-)

Comment: I believe like Jerry's comment on the questions it's a typo. Some implementations might allow "+*", either as a plus or as a asterisk, but I don't know of any. It's more likely it would throw an error rather than return null - but I don't even know what language the OP is using, so *shrug*

(Still can't comment on others' questions, for crying out loud.)

Comment: @DimeCadmium when the data is like `':abc:xyz:lmn'` then the reg_exp returns `':abc:xyz:lmn'`. Even, if there are more asteriks after `lmn` like `:abc:xyz:lmn:def`, the reg_exp returns again `':abc:xyz:lmn'`. The same results are obtained when I exclude the `*`. I want to know how the `*` is going to effect, if there is change in data or how does the data should be, so that `*` can have affect ?

Comment: The asterisk (*) will have no effect, ever, as the regex is currently written (I think). It should be invalid. As far as I can tell, this command will return 6 characters formatted `:a:b:c` (which means `':[^:]:[^:]:[^:]'` would be an equivalent regex).

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it on an online regex debugger and you can see the results here http://regex101.com/r/vG5oV3 along with an explanation of every part of the regex.

If you use your regex as it is in the question, the end '+*' does not make any sense and is not a correct regular expression (as Liath is mentioning in a comment)

`:` outside the [] is the character that is matched in the expression and `[^:]+` means match from one to unlimited characters that are not `:`

So it begins by finding the first `:` then matches all the characters until it finds another `:` and then does that again, three times in total.

Comment: In the debugger you've mentioned, its showing an error. but, when run in sqlplus its not giving any error and the result is same as explained in your answer.

Comment: The `*` means that the last expression, in this case `[^:]+` should be repeated 0 or more times. In practice, this negates the last `+`, making it superfluous. The regex is equivalent to `:[^:]+:[^:]+:[^:]*`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example. The third column is an equivalent regular expression that is shorter/clearer in my opinion:

```
SQL> with t as
  2  ( select 'abc:de:fghijk:lmnopqrs:tuvw:xyz' data from dual union all
  3    select 'abcde:fg:hi:jklmnopqr:s:tu:v:wxyz' from dual union all
  4    select ':abcde:fg:hi:jklmnopqr:s:tu:v:wxyz' from dual
  5  )
  6  select data
  7       , substr
  8         ( regexp_substr(data,':[^:]+:[^:]+:[^:]+*', 1, 1)
  9         , length(regexp_substr(data,':[^:]+:[^:]+:*', 1, 1)) + 6
 10         )
 11       , substr(regexp_substr(data,':[^:]+',1,3),7)
 12    from t
 13  /

DATA                               SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(DATA,':[^:]+: SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(DATA,':
---------------------------------- ---------------------------------- ----------------------------
abc:de:fghijk:lmnopqrs:tuvw:xyz    qrs                                qrs
abcde:fg:hi:jklmnopqr:s:tu:v:wxyz  opqr                               opqr
:abcde:fg:hi:jklmnopqr:s:tu:v:wxyz

3 rows selected.
```

regards,
Rob.